# Como poner tablas de multiplicar en 3 columnas

Tags: c

Me dejaron de trabajo hacer un código en **C** de las tablas de multiplicar del 0 al 11, cada tabla llegando del 0 al 10, y **tienen que estar ordenadas en 3 columnas**.
Este es mi código:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main () {
    int i, i2, j, multi;
    
    for(i = 0, i2 = 0, j = 1; i2 <= 11; i++, j++) {
        multi = i * i2;
        if(i > 10) {
            i2++;
            i = 0;
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("%d x %d = %d\n", i2, i, multi);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Funcionan bien todas las tablas pero tienen que estar ordenadas en filas de 3, y el mío solo va en 1 columna.

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar un ejemplo de cómo se debería ver?

Comment: 0 x 0 = 0      1 x 0 = 0      2 x 0 = 0
0 x 1 = 0      1 x 1 = 1      2 x 1 = 2
0 x 2 = 0      1 x 2 = 2      2 x 2 = 4
...
0 x 10 = 0     1 x 10 = 10    2 x 10 = 20
Algo asi (Copia el texto y pegale en un comentario y haz como si lo fueras a mandar para verlo bien)

Comment: En los comentarios no se ve bien. Y en realidad no funciona bien porque dice 2 x 0 = 11, 3 x 0 = 22 y así. ¿Por qué no lo haces con 2 bucles?

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon en la pregunta tanto el resultado esperado como el obtenido. Ten presente que los comentarios son efímeros: agrega siempre información relevante a tu pregunta editándola.